# wxFormBuilder Toolbar Spacing

Tags: c++, user-interface, wxwidgets, wxformbuilder

I am creating a layout using wxFormBuilder. I have a frame, wxBoxSizer (wxToolBar and wxListBook in it) and a wxMenuBar with a wxMenu in it, like so: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVc5J.png

I then view the XRC Window and it seems ok: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnOYv.png

Then, I add a tool to the toolbar, like so: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrMRa.png

The problem shows up when I then check the XRC Window and I see that there is a blank space between the menubar and the toolbar: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N93nc.png

How can I remove this gap? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normal, default frame toolbar shouldn't be added to the sizer managing the rest of the frame elements because it's already handled by `wxFrame` itself automatically, so if you just need a toolbar positioned in the standard location (as opposed to having a toolbar in the middle of a window or something like that) you just shouldn't do this. I'm still not sure where does the gap come from but I am pretty sure that it will disappear once you stop adding toolbar to the sizer.